# How to use sprite image in XML file?

Tags: android, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/splash"
   >
```

I´m using android:background to define the Background... Its possible to use sprite background in XML file?

Comment: Can anybody help me?

Comment: I still don't understand your question, but you can use any images as a background.